# Making a postgres query less expensive for the DB

Tags: database, postgresql, join

In a SQL query I have to join many tables and its very expensive for the DB.

In the DB a hostgroup has many host, there are like 20 hostgroups, and there is 4 hostgroups that I don't use...

I was wandering if I add a "not in" operator in my query, excluding those 4 hostgroup, the query will be less expensive? or just make thing worst using more resources on the db?

this is my query, just in case...

```
select history.clock, hstgrp.name as hostgroup, hstgrp.groupid as hgid , hosts.name as hostname ,
       items.name as item, hosts.hostid, history.value as porcentaje, items.key_ as key ,items.itemid,
       applications.name as appname, applications.applicationid as appid
       FROM history
       join items_applications on history.itemid = items_applications.itemid
       join applications on items_applications.applicationid = applications.applicationid
       join items on items.itemid = history.itemid
       join hosts on items.hostid = hosts.hostid
       join hosts_groups on hosts.hostid = hosts_groups.hostid
       join hstgrp on hosts_groups.groupid = hstgrp.groupid
       where lower(items.name) SIMILAR TO lower('Used disk space%|Used disk space on%')
       and hstgrp.name not in ('Discovered', 'Discover VMs')  <==============
```

Answer (score 0):

The additional filter sure cannot harm, but unless it is very selective, it will probably not reduce the execution time significantly.

I am reduced to guessing, since you didn't add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output to the question, but I'd assume that the query returns a lot of rows and is bound to be slow.

You could change the `SIMILAR TO` condition to

```
WHERE lower(items.name) LIKE lower('Used disk space%')
```

and support it with an index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON items (lower(name) text_pattern_ops);
```

Perhaps that will speed up the execution somewhat.